# Email Notification scenarios

Tags: visualforce

I have web form page in that I have a 'SUBMIT' button.
When the submit button is clicked 3 things should happen.

1. A record is inserted or updated(which is working great!)
2. Directing to the Thankyou page(which is working great!)
3. Now client want me to implement whenever a submit button is clicked
   email notification should be send to the user.

How to implement 3rd point?
I have some like workflow rule,apex trigger and also Apex class.
But is there any best/easy way to implement?

Comment: Wfr on the record that is inserted/updated?

Comment: How did you manage to make the first two points work?

Comment: Using a standard controller contact,and a extension.Its a very simple web form page with contact fields and a standard save.Extension is used to redirect the page to thank you page when a save is hit.

Comment: Extension:public class thankyoupageredirectext {
    
    private final contact con;

    
    public thankyoupageredirectext (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.con = (contact)stdController.getRecord();

    }
   
     public PageReference save(){
       
        upsert con;
      
        PageReference reRend = new PageReference('/apex/Thankyou');
        reRend.setRedirect(true);
        return reRend;
    }

}

Comment: Let me know any other way to do it.